# AngularJS ng-model not bound to Kendo UI dropdown when datasource data not in range

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-datasource

I'm developing a complex application using angularjs vs Kendo UI.

Here is the simple view:

```
<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <h4>DropDown</h4>
        <select kendo-drop-down-list="" options="options" ng-model="selectedProduct"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is simple js:

```
<script>
    angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
        .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
            $scope.selectedProduct = 51;
            $scope.options = {
              autoBind: true,
              dataTextField: "ProductName",
              dataValueField: "ProductID",
              filter: "contains",
              suggest: true,
              dataSource: {
                transport: {
                  read: {
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    url: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products"
                  }
                },
                pageSize: 50
              }
            };
        })
</script>
```

Now you can see that `$scope.selectedProduct = 51;` and `pageSize: 50` and that means that the dropdown is never get initialized with a predefined value. Feel free to update `$scope.selectedProduct` with the value 1 to 50 and see the dropdown actually initialized. This is the simplest code to highlight the problem. In real world this is pretty much the same scenario so I'd like to figure out how to make this binding work in an elegant way.

Here is a dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/OpeqO

Comment: Can you just do: `pageSize: Math.max(50, $scope.selectedProduct) ` ?

Comment: Thanks @o4ohel Well, first the id can be non numeric.. And I don't want to take more than certain amount of records because of performance. So that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the selectedProduct and if the new value is null you can change the default.

```
$scope.$watch('selectedProduct',function(newVal,oldVal,$scope){
    if(newVal==null){                
        $scope.selectedProduct = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you mislead my question. The question here is how to force load selected option into dropdown when the first bunch of records does not contain that record.

Comment: One of my ideas was to prefilter by the model value but when I try to filter afterwards (through drop down filtering) it just adds up another filter after prefilter condition.